How to fix this error "No overload matches this call" in Yup(react-hook-form)(reactjs-typescript)
 const schema = Yup.object({
        logo_image_name: Yup.string().required('Logo image name is required.'),
        favicon: Yup.string().required('Favicon is required.'),
        logo_type: Yup.mixed<LogoType>().oneOf(['logo', 'logo_text', 'text'], 'Invalid logo type. Choose from logo, logo_text, or text.').required('Logo type is required.'),
        is_same_as_brand_logo: Yup.boolean().required('Please specify if the favicon is the same as the brand logo.'),
        name: Yup.string()
            .nullable()
            .when('logo_type', {
                is: (value: string) => value === 'logo_text' || value === 'text',
                then: Yup.string().required('Name is required when logo type is "logo_text" or "text".'),
                otherwise: Yup.string().notRequired(),
            }),
        font_family: Yup.string()
            .nullable()
            .when('logo_type', {
                is: (value) => value === 'logo_text' || value === 'text',
                then: Yup.string().required('Font family is required for "logo_text" or "text".'),
                otherwise: Yup.string().notRequired(),
            }),
        font_weight: Yup.string()
            .nullable()
            .when('logo_type', {
                is: (value) => value === 'logo_text' || value === 'text',
                then: Yup.string().required('Font weight is required for "logo_text" or "text".'),
                otherwise: Yup.string().notRequired(),
            }),
    }).required('Form data is required.');

i have this code but it always give me error like
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(keys: string | string[], builder: ConditionBuilder<StringSchema<string | null | undefined, AnyObject, undefined, "">>): StringSchema<...>', gave the following error.
    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'is' does not exist in type 'ConditionBuilder<StringSchema<string | null | undefined, AnyObject, undefined, "">>'.ts(2769)

Im stuck here...
so how to handle this issue or provide any other alternative way to handle

 const schema = Yup.object({
    logo_image_name: Yup.string().required('Logo image name is required.'),
    favicon: Yup.string().required('Favicon is required.'),
    logo_type: Yup.mixed<LogoType>().oneOf(['logo', 'logo_text', 'text'], 'Invalid logo type. Choose from logo, logo_text, or text.').required('Logo type is required.'),
    is_same_as_brand_logo: Yup.boolean().required('Please specify if the favicon is the same as the brand logo.'),
    name: Yup.string()
        .nullable()
        .when('logo_type', (logoType: any, customSchema) =>
            logoType && (logoType === 'logo_text' || logoType === 'text') ? customSchema.required('Name is required when logo type is "logo_text" or "text".') : customSchema.nullable(),
        ),
    font_family: Yup.string()
        .nullable()
        .when('logo_type', (logoType: any, customSchema) =>
            logoType === 'logo_text' || logoType === 'text' ? customSchema.required('Font family is required for "logo_text" or "text".') : customSchema,
        ),
    font_weight: Yup.string()
        .nullable()
        .when('logo_type', (logoType: any, customSchema) =>
            logoType === 'logo_text' || logoType === 'text' ? customSchema.required('Font weight is required for "logo_text" or "text".') : customSchema,
        ),
}).required('Form data is required.');

I just fixed with this changes...
